# Continues Marquee in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, marquee

I'm developing news website in asp.net, and I want to make news bar that move news from right to left , I have did it with Marquee tag but the problem is I want it to repeat its content without any jabs, as it is finished and then start from the beginning, I want it to be repeated continuously

any help please

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

If you must have marquee functionality then try using a jQuery plugin such as [simplyScroll v1](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html) which supports continuous scrolling (ie. it seamlessly wraps around). Note, however, that marquees are considered bad for usability and accessibility in the same way the old `<blink>` tag was - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element#Usability_problems

Comment: ok it is not a must to use marquee, if you know any asp.net control that may do the same functionality it will be great

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will help you:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function objWidth(obj) {
        if (obj.offsetWidth) return obj.offsetWidth;
        if (obj.clip) return obj.clip.width;
        return 0;
    }
    var mqr = [];

    function mq(id) {
        this.mqo = document.getElementById(id);
        var wid = objWidth(this.mqo.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]) + 5;
        var fulwid = objWidth(this.mqo);
        var txt = this.mqo.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
        this.mqo.innerHTML = '';
        var heit = this.mqo.style.height;
        this.mqo.onmouseout = function () {
            mqRotate(mqr);
        };
        this.mqo.onmouseover = function () {
            clearTimeout(mqr[0].TO);
        };
        this.mqo.ary = [];
        var maxw = Math.ceil(fulwid / wid) + 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < maxw; i++) {
            this.mqo.ary[i] = document.createElement('div');
            this.mqo.ary[i].innerHTML = txt;
            this.mqo.ary[i].style.position = 'absolute';
            this.mqo.ary[i].style.left = (wid * i) + 'px';
            this.mqo.ary[i].style.width = wid + 'px';
            this.mqo.ary[i].style.height = heit;
            this.mqo.appendChild(this.mqo.ary[i]);
        }
        mqr.push(this.mqo);
    }

    function mqRotate(mqr) {
        if (!mqr) return;
        for (var j = mqr.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
            maxa = mqr[j].ary.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < maxa; i++) {
                var x = mqr[j].ary[i].style;
                x.left = (parseInt(x.left, 10) - 1) + 'px';
            }
            var y = mqr[j].ary[0].style;
            if (parseInt(y.left, 10) + parseInt(y.width, 10) < 0) {
                var z = mqr[j].ary.shift();
                z.style.left = (parseInt(z.style.left) + parseInt(z.style.width) * maxa) + 'px';
                mqr[j].ary.push(z);
            }
        }
        mqr[0].TO = setTimeout('mqRotate(mqr)', 10);
    }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        new mq('m1');
        mqRotate(mqr);
    }

    window.onload = start;
 </script>

 <div id="m1" class="marquee">
    <span>Example for Continous Text</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this site has implementation that meets your requirement http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_example.htm

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294048/continuously-scrolling-horizontal-ticker-containing-images-in-jquery)

Comment: actually no, This example my help you understand what I want, http://javascript.about.com/library/blcmarquee1.htm , but this is for images and also is not connecting to database it is static

Answer (score 0):

If you want a news scroller you can try this plugin for jQuery [liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html), I don't know if you want to refresh the news without page reload?

Link: http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then you can give value for the literal.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "get data from database";
    string text = "<MARQUEE>" + str + "</MARQUEE>";
    Literal1.Text = text;
}
```

I think this website is useful.
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html