# ASP.Net, Marquee

Tags: c#, asp.net, marquee

I have a marquee which is getting data from database. And every time I go through pages or refresh marquee starts from the beginning position. (most right side of page). Is there any way to not to begin marquee?

Comment: Should not allow the page to load. Try to use page partial load.

Comment: Page Partial Load? Could you please give me some link or example site link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239263/continues-marquee-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can get marque only once first time page load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           //Call you method here which can get data on page load, in a page load method 
        }
```